# recursion on python instrumentation

Tags: python, recursion

I have the below code, basically, its to test if any element of the array
add up to a number.
I use recursion but I am not sure when it is returning and wonder a way I can track that. I am using juypter notebook.

Is there a simple way for me to examine the call-stack.
I have two implementation.

```
def gg(arr,k):
    #end=len(arr);
    #ptr=0;
    rr=0;
    #for ( i=0; i < arr.length; i++):
    for index, item in enumerate(arr):
        yy=arr[index+1:len(arr)]

        #print(arr[index])
        for index2,item2 in enumerate(yy):
            print(arr[index]);
            print(yy[index2]);
            print(" ");
            if(yy[index2]+arr[index]==k):
               # rr=True;
                rr=1;
                return rr;
def gg2(arr,k):
    r=0;
    if(len(arr)==2):
        if(arr[0]+arr[1]==k):
            print("yes");
            print(arr[0]);
            print(k);
            print(arr[1]);
            print("yes");
            #print(arr[0]);
            #print(arr[1]);
            #print("");
            r=1;
            return r;
    else:
            xx=arr[1:len(arr)];
            print(xx);
            del arr[1];
            yy=arr;
            print(yy);
            print(" ");
            gg2(yy,k);
            gg2(xx,k);



zz=[10,2,3,6,11]
gg2(zz,17)
```

Comment: Have a look at the [traceback](https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html) python module. I think you'll find the functions you need there.

Comment: Specifically, consider `from traceback import print_stack`

Comment: You never made use of any return value. And please remove these semicolons!